# Determine which combinations of vectors will sum to another vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, linear-algebra

I am using Python  3 to try to find what linear combinations of a set of vectors will sum to another vector. I am using numpy arrays as vectors.

For example, I would have a target vector and matrix "choices" containing all the possible choices of vectors:

```
targetvector0 = numpy.array([0, 1, 2])

choices = numpy.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0]])
```

I need something that would return all possible combinations and their integer multiples (need them to be integer multiples) that sum to the target and ignore those that don't:

```
option1 = [[1], [2], [0], [0]]
option2 = [[1], [0], [1], [0]]
```

I found some info on `numpy.linalg.solve(x, y)`, but it doesn't quite do what I'm looking for or I don't know how to use it effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the multiples you are searching are all positive.

You can carefully increment the multiples, studying all the combinations that give results not greater than the target vector.

```
import numpy as np


def solve(target_vector, choices):
    nb_choices, n = choices.shape
    factors = np.zeros((1, nb_choices), dtype=np.int)
    i = 0

    while True:
        if i == nb_choices - 1:
            return

        factors[0, i] += 1
        difference_to_target = factors.dot(choices) - targetvector

        found_solution = np.all(difference_to_target == 0)
        factors_too_high = np.any(difference_to_target > 0)

        if found_solution:
            yield factors.copy()

        if found_solution or factors_too_high:
            factors[0, :i + 1] = 0
            i += 1
            continue

        i = 0


targetvector = np.array([0, 1, 2])
choices = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0]])
print(list(solve(targetvector, choices)))
# [array([[1, 2, 0, 0]]), array([[1, 0, 1, 0]])]
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes, the multiples will be positive along with the choices. Is there any resources you would recommend in regards to the code you have written? I think I follow, but want to get a more solid understanding before using it.

Comment: I did it by myself, so I cannot give you any specific link. I cannot tell you if it is optimal, but it seems to work.